# Pushed to last remote branch when switching branch

Tags: eclipse, git

I've been using the git plugin for Eclipse for months without problems.
But lately (after a bad forgotten manipulation, probably) when I switch branch using the contextual menu "Team -> Switch To", the modifications are pushed to the last branch.
Now, each time I'm doing a push or pull after a switch, I need to remember to modify the ref mappings.

A temporary fix has been to set the mappings in "Configure push for remote origin" to :

```
refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

but I prefer to avoid pushing all branches each time.

Is there a way to go back to the usual behavior where the current local branch is pushed to the correct remote location after a switch, without having to modify the ref mappings each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually simple:

I just needed to remove all ref mappings declared in the push configuration. The system pushes the current branch to the corresponding one in the remote.